# Why I get Class '\App\Teacher' not found error

Tags: php, laravel

I change the location of a Model from its original location (put into a new directory in the Laravel project) and change the namespace also. But now I get the following error.

I change the namespace of the Model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Teacher\Teacher;
//namespace App;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: First off, I think your namespace has one Teacher too many. When defining namespaces, you don't include the class name. Also, the error seem to suggest that you're trying to use the class somewhere by the namespace App\Teacher, when that's not where the class is located.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't use the **right** file path.
as your path from namespace **App\Models\Teacher\Teacher**

try the following in model:

```
use App\Models\Teacher\Teacher;
```

Comment: Why sould one do that? Can you explain that?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your model namespace

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Teacher;
```

and use anywhere

```
use App\Models\Teacher\Teacher;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace is `App\Models\Teacher` not `App\Models\Teacher\Teacher`.

In your controller use `use App\Models\Teacher\Teacher` command to use the model.